# Como buscar un rango de valores en una tabla en Excel

Tags: excel, formulas

Quiero buscar un rango de valores es decir de una columna donde tengo varios valores me gustaria buscarlos en mi tabla y saber si estan estos valores ahi, los valores y mi tabla estan en archivos diferentes y los valores que quiero buscar en la tabla estan en la columna 4, como puedo hacer este Vlookup?

Digamos que estos son los datos que quiero buscar

```
Azul
Amarillo
Rojo
Verde
Negro
Cafe
```

de mi tabla que esta así, obviamente ahi mas registros pero no puedo ponerlos todos solo es para ejemplo

```
ID       Nombre        Años     ColorFavorito
1        Jose            12             Azul
2        Ana             15             Azul
3        Maria           11             Rojo
4        Alejandro       21             Cafe
5        Fernando        10            Negro
6        Josue           13             Cafe
```

Comment: Puedes usar CONTAR.SI para contar si el valor (por ejemplo Azul) aparece en la columna de ColorFavorito. Si el resultado es 0 es que no está.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supongamos que tienes dos hojas, **DATOS** y **BUSQUEDA**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la hoja **BUSQUEDA** agregas esta fórmula en la celda **B1**

```
=VLOOKUP(A1;DATOS!D:D;1;0)
```

Entonces, va a buscar la palabra **Azul** (primer parámetro) en la hoja **DATOS**, el rango de columnas sería solo la **D** (segundo parámetro), te traerá los valores de esa misma columna (tercer parámetro) y el cuarto parámetro indica que los datos no están ordenados.

Si los datos están en libros *o archivos* diferentes, simplemente debes agregar la ruta al otro archivo en el segundo parámetro.

Comment: Yo creo que esto es un apaño más que una solución. Si VLOOKUP no encuentra nada devuelve un error. Mejor CONTAR.SI para que no haya errores en las celdas.

Comment: Si entindo eso, solo que tomando tu ejemplo en la hoja busqueda donde tengo los datos que quiero buscar no estan en la columna A sino que estan en no se la D y vi en algunas paginas que no se puede buscar en columnas que no sea la primera y ese es mi problema

Comment: Permíteme corregirte. _En la hoja de búsqueda los datos a buscar están en la columna D_... Simplemente mueve la fórmula a la celda que quieras y reemplaza el origen en el primer parámetro en la fórmula `=VLOOKUP(D1;DATOS!D:D;1;0)`. Por supuesto que puedes buscar de esta manera.

Comment: Ahora, si lo que necesitas es mostrar otros datos de la hoja **DATOS** basándote en el color favorito, entonces si es necesario pasar la columna **ColorFavorito** a la primera posición, _columna **A** por ejemplo_ y esto es lo que te están diciendo en las paginas que estás consultando. En cualquier caso, déjame un comentario o edita tu pregunta con mayores detalles para darle claridad al problema.